# css media queries: target mobile devices without specifying width, pixel ratio, etc

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-devices

Let's say I just want to target every tablet and phone, regardless of size, is there a media query for this? Is it possible to do this without specifying a size? Or is using a size the only way to target mobile devices, and not desktops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), `@media handeld` is mentioned but it has perhaps no browser support.

So, no.

However, you might find [this site](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript) useful, it explains other some media query techniques for mobile.

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with this for a few days, but a good way to check for handheld devices is the max-device-width. Desktop pc's don't send this to the browser, but most (if not all) handhelds do use this.

In my case I wanted to show a compressed version of the site on all devices (including desktop) when below a certain width, for which I used

`@media all and (max-width: 640px)`

But a certain overlay popup that used `position: fixed` had to be changed on handhelds only (because the css property works in all desktop browsers but not on all handhelds). So for that I used an additional rule:

`@media all and (max-device-width: 640px)`

In which I target all handhelds below 640 but not desktop browsers. Incidentally, this also doesn't target iPads (which is how I wanted it) because it has a higher device width than 640px.

If you just want to target all devices just pick a low min width (1px) so that it doesn't exclude any device regardless of width.

Comment: max-device-width is reported by Chrome before anyone goes down this path.

Comment: I had to break my media queries only ambition and use JS to target smaller browser windows.

Comment: How do you deal with all the good phones that have width >= 720px ? I mean outside of the apple world, 720p has been the norm for ages, and I don't see how just max-device-width is an acceptable solution.

Comment: In this specific case I needed only devices smaller than 640px. If you read the entire answer, I also state that using a `min-device-width` of `1` will capture all devices (and still not deskops). It's the `device` part that captures the device, not the width

Comment: you didnt update your answer... it doesnt only target handheld

Comment: Oops. I have the feeling the answer is kinda outdated nowadays anyway. I'll see if I can find some updated information, it's been ages since I worked on the project I needed this for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll have too much luck with a pure css approach. You'll want to do something along the lines of the modernizer.js approach and us JS to detect device and append a class name to body based on that.

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Then include that class in your media queries to special case mobile devices of varying sizes.