# Need to hide a particular menu item in mobile version for a static website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a static website with approx. 8 menu items. I am writing media queries for mobile version. But I need to hide a particular menu item like Gallery in mobile as I don't want it be shown on mobile. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: @media (min-width:600px) {
    .menu {
        display:none;
    }
}​

Try this code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352919/css-media-queries-target-mobile-devices-without-specifying-width-pixel-ratio

Comment: Hi Rohit, hope your answer will hide the whole menu not a particular menu item like gallery ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none;` on that div with media query, which you want to hide.

Comment: Hi, I dont want to hide the whole div just a single menu item in mobile version ... thanks.